# How to control casting of null int field to varchar in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

First of all I would like to know how does `CAST` work with `NULL` fields and how does it behave when the value is `NULL`?

For example in the expression:

```
(CAST(INT_FIELD as nvarchar(100))
```

what happens if the value `INT_FIELD` is `NULL`?

The reason is that when I'm trying to do the following:

```
SELECT (CAST(INT_FIELD as nvarchar(100)) + ' ' + SOME_OTHER_FIELD FROM SOME_TABLE;
```

I'm getting `NULL` even though the `SOME_OTHER_FIELD` is not null. I'm guessing it has some kind of logic that `NULL + something = NULL` but I'm not sure.

How can I control this behavior?

Comment: Why are you casting an integer field to `nvarchar(100)`? Max length is 11.

Comment: @Martin Smith - I just used it as a dummy value, thanks for the tip though, I didn't know that max length is 11. What is the max length for a decimal?

Comment: depends on precision and scale. But 40 I would have though for max precision `38` with a decimal point and a minus symbol.

Comment: Read up on [CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-concat-null-yields-null-transact-sql).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to use [ISNULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or [COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), since most row operation between a `NULL` is gonna result in `NULL`. [CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) of a `NULL` returns `NULL` and `NULL` + something is also `NULL`. In your example you should do something like this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(CAST(INT_FIELD as nvarchar(100)),'') + ' ' + ISNULL(SOME_OTHER_FIELD,'')
FROM SOME_TABLE;
```

Of course, in my example, if both fields are `NULL` it will return ' ' instead of '', but you get the idea.

Comment: Roll on Denali and the [`CONCAT`](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/concat-function-in-sql-server) function

Answer (score 4):

Look into COALESCE, where you can find the first non-null and return 0 if all are null, e.g:

```
SELECT (CAST(COALESCE(INT_FIELD,0) as nvarchar(100)) + ' ' + SOME_OTHER_FIELD FROM SOME_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using `COALESCE`

```
SELECT COALESCE(CAST(INT_FIELD as nvarchar(100), '') + ' ' + SOME_OTHER_FIELD FROM SOME_TABLE;
```

Comment: What is the difference between COALESCE and ISNULL?

Comment: A detailed difference between COALESCE and ISNULL is explained clearly here in this blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqltips/archive/2008/06/26/differences-between-isnull-and-coalesce.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Normally, `NULL` +(-,/,*, etc) `something` = `NULL`. 
You can use

```
SELECT ISNULL(CAST(INT_FIELD as nvarchar(100)),'') 
+ ' ' + ISNULL(SOME_OTHER_FIELD FROM SOME_TABLE,'')
```

or you can `SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF` ([more details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx))